# JavaScript error: "document is not defined"

Tags: javascript, compiler-errors

I'm trying to work through a JavaScript tutorial on Udemy. I'm following along with the instructor in the DOM section where we make changes to a Pig Game. I'm working in Visual Studio Code and refreshing UI in the Chrome browser. I'm in the right directory, but when I use commands like document.querySelector and such, when I try to run it I get "ReferenceError: document is not defined".

On top of that, I also get an Uncaught TypeError is the console that says: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'textContent' of null" This is in reference to the line that tries to update the current score.

I'm not sure what to do about these errors. No other posts on stackoverflow that I've seen have been of much help. I'm new to JavaScript (and relatively new to coding in general). Any help would be appreciated.

Here's my code:

```js
var scores, roundScore, activePlayer;

scores = [0, 0];
roundScore = 0;
activePlayer = 0;

document.querySelector('.dice').style.display = 'none';

document.getElementById('score-0').textContent = '0';
document.getElementById('score-1').textContent = '0';
document.getElementById('current-0').textContent = '0';
document.getElementById('current-1').textContent = '0';


document.querySelector('.btn-roll').addEventListener('click',function(){
    // 1. Random number
    var dice = Math.floor(Math.random()*6) + 1;

    // 2. Display the result
    var diceDOM = document.querySelector('.dice');
    diceDOM.style.display = 'block';
    diceDOM.src = 'dice-' + dice + '.png';

    // 3. Update the round score IF the rolled number was NOT a 1.
    if (dice !== 1) {
        // Add score
        roundScore += dice;
        document.querySelector('#current'- + activePlayer).textContent = roundScore;
    } else {
        // Next player
    }
});
```

```css
/**********************************************
*** GENERAL
**********************************************/

.final-score {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    top: 520px;
    color: #555;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-family: 'Lato';
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 160px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.final-score:focus { outline: none; }

#dice-1 { top: 120px; }
#dice-2 { top: 250px; }


* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    
}

.clearfix::after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}

body {
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(62, 20, 20, 0.4), rgba(62, 20, 20, 0.4)), url(back.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    font-family: Lato;
    font-weight: 300;
    position: relative;
    height: 100vh;
    color: #555;
}

.wrapper {
    width: 1000px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    background-color: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0px 10px 50px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    overflow: hidden;
}

.player-0-panel,
.player-1-panel {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    height: 600px;
    padding: 100px;
}



/**********************************************
*** PLAYERS
**********************************************/

.player-name {
    font-size: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    font-weight: 100;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    position: relative;
}

.player-score {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 80px;
    font-weight: 100;
    color: #EB4D4D;
    margin-bottom: 130px;
}

.active { background-color: #f7f7f7; }
.active .player-name { font-weight: 300; }

.active .player-name::after {
    content: "\2022";
    font-size: 47px;
    position: absolute;
    color: #EB4D4D;
    top: -7px;
    right: 10px;
    
}

.player-current-box {
    background-color: #EB4D4D;
    color: #fff;
    width: 40%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 12px;
    text-align: center;
}

.player-current-label {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #222;
}

.player-current-score {
    font-size: 30px;
}

button {
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    color: #555;
    background: none;
    border: none;
    font-family: Lato;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-weight: 300;
    transition: background-color 0.3s, color 0.3s;
}

button:hover { font-weight: 600; }
button:hover i { margin-right: 20px; }

button:focus {
    outline: none;
}

i {
    color: #EB4D4D;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 15px;
    font-size: 32px;
    line-height: 1;
    vertical-align: text-top;
    margin-top: -4px;
    transition: margin 0.3s;
}

.btn-new { top: 45px;}
.btn-roll { top: 403px;}
.btn-hold { top: 467px;}

.dice {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 178px;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    height: 100px;
    box-shadow: 0px 10px 60px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.10);
}

.winner { background-color: #f7f7f7; }
.winner .player-name { font-weight: 300; color: #EB4D4D; }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100,300,600" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <link href="http://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        
        <title>Pig Game</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="wrapper clearfix">
            <div class="player-0-panel active">
                <div class="player-name" id="name-0">Player 1</div>
                <div class="player-score" id="score-0">43</div>
                <div class="player-current-box">
                    <div class="player-current-label">Current</div>
                    <div class="player-current-score" id="current-0">11</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            
            <div class="player-1-panel">
                <div class="player-name" id="name-1">Player 2</div>
                <div class="player-score" id="score-1">72</div>
                <div class="player-current-box">
                    <div class="player-current-label">Current</div>
                    <div class="player-current-score" id="current-1">0</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            
            <button class="btn-new"><i class="ion-ios-plus-outline"></i>New game</button>
            <button class="btn-roll"><i class="ion-ios-loop"></i>Roll dice</button>
            <button class="btn-hold"><i class="ion-ios-download-outline"></i>Hold</button>
            
            <input type="text" placeholder="Final score" class="final-score">
            
            <img src="dice-5.png" alt="Dice" class="dice" id="dice-1">
            <img src="dice-5.png" alt="Dice" class="dice" id="dice-2">
        </div>
        
        <!--<script src="app.js"></script>-->
        <script src="challenges.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Well for one thing `'#current'- + activePlayer` does not make sense; you need the `-` inside the quotes, not outside.

Comment: There it is. Thanks!